# Apache AuthzSendUnauthorizedOnFailure?

Tags: authorization, apache2.4

I was wondering if I can force apache to send HTTP 401 instead of HTTP 403 in case any condition inside RequireAll fails.
Surprisingly I found AuthzSendForbiddenOnFailure, which forces 403 instead of 401.  But what about opposite?
How I can force apache reask for the login and password in case authorization fails?

**Edit:**
I looked at the debug log right now.
The thing is that if I will put just *Require valid user* in the *RequireAll* section, in the log I would see *"denied (no authentocated user yet)"*.  Yet if I will put *Require env SMTH* additionally, apache will check *Require valid user* but then, after it will fail with *"denied (no authentocated user yet)"*, it will also check my second Require and will fail just with *"denied"* and throw HTTP 403.  I think this is a bug.  Why apache checks for a second Require in RequireAll if the first one failed already?

**Edit2:**
It seems that it wasn't implemented yet:
https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/aaa/mod_authz_core.c#766

```c
if (child_result != AUTHZ_NEUTRAL) {
                /*
                 * Handling of AUTHZ_DENIED/AUTHZ_DENIED_NO_USER: Return
                 * AUTHZ_DENIED_NO_USER if providing a user may change the
                 * result, AUTHZ_DENIED otherwise.
                 */
                if (section->op == AUTHZ_LOGIC_AND) {
                    if (child_result == AUTHZ_DENIED) {
                        auth_result = child_result;
                        break;
                    }
                    if ((child_result == AUTHZ_DENIED_NO_USER
                         && auth_result != AUTHZ_DENIED)
                        || (auth_result == AUTHZ_NEUTRAL)) {
                        auth_result = child_result;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    /* AUTHZ_LOGIC_OR */
                    if (child_result == AUTHZ_GRANTED) {
                        auth_result = child_result;
                        break;
                    }
                    if ((child_result == AUTHZ_DENIED_NO_USER
                         && auth_result == AUTHZ_DENIED)
                        || (auth_result == AUTHZ_NEUTRAL)) {
                        auth_result = child_result;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Excellent question and thanks for the edits. I just had the same problem. In my case I have "Require env HAS_ACCESS" and "Require user x" in RequireAny. That keeps returning 403. I read the apache docs in a way that this is actually intended behavior. But I'd really like a way to tell the user to supply a username, so to return a 401.

Comment: @moritz, I am not sure what to do yet.  I submitted it as a bug: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63800 . Just waiting right now.  I wonder if I should make appropriate changes in the source code and compile it myself...